# Как получить длину линии в leader line JS?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно в зависимости от длины линии менять ее тип с "straight" на "grid". В документации на [GitHub][1] не нашел ничего подобного. Как я могу это сделать? возможно я упускаю что-то очевидное.
у меня есть

```js
for (let i = 0; i < ar_for_lines.length - 1; i++){
                if (ar_for_lines[i].id != ''){
                        line = new LeaderLine(
                            document.getElementById(ar_for_lines[i].id),
                            document.getElementById(ar_for_lines[i+1].id)
                        );
                        line.color = 'rgba(30, 130, 250, 0.5)';
                        line.setOptions({startSocket: 'right', endSocket: 'left'});
                        line.path = 'grid'                     
                }
            }
```

я хочу менять path в зависимости от длины линии. или каким-то другим способом менять форму линии сохраняя line.path = 'grid'
[1]: https://github.com/anseki/leader-line

Comment: добавь больше информации в вопрос. И пример кода который у тебя уже есть

Comment: также непонятно кто меняет длину

Comment: добавь всю необходимую информацию прямо в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вопрос и документацию, то у line есть ключ size, пример:

```
line.path = line.size > 5 ? 'grid' : 'straight'
```

Comment: size - это не длина, а толщина линий, т.е. на сколько линия будет жирной

Comment: @Konsul Тогда могу предложить только искать стрелку по классу 'leader-line' и брать оттуда габариты svg, расчитывая либо по координатам, либо как то в тупую по ширине и высоте.